# Keeping content centered when zooming

Tags: html, css, browser, zooming

I have a simple example of centered content using HTML and CSS ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysyxV/)).  The screenshot is below:

[image: Unzoomed content]

HTML:

```
<body class="" lang="en-US">
    <div class="wrapper">
        Some stuff
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html 
{
    background: lightgray; /* Background color of whole window */
    border: 2px solid orange; /* Debug */
    width: 20em; /* The width of the content */
    margin: 2em auto;
}

body
{
    border: 2px solid purple;
}

.wrapper
{
    background: lightgray; /* Background color of whole window */
    border: 2px solid orange; /* Debug */
}
```

When I zoom in using the browser zoom, the content stays on the left hand side as you zoom in:

[image: Zoomed Content]

What I would like to have happen is the content say in the middle of the window as you zoom:

[image: Desired zoom result]

Is there an easy way to do this using CSS.  I dont want to use jquery or any other way if possible.

**Update** as @Mr Lister points out, `this "problem" has nothing top do with zoom. The very same thing happens if the user makes the window narrower until the horizontal scrollbar appears. Are you saying you want the scrollbar to automatically go to the center then too? That would require Javascript`

I don't think I would want that. It seems like the user experience from that might be a bit weird. I don't want to force it to be in the center all the time, not allowing them to move to other sections of the page. Just keep it centered when the horizontal scrollbar first appears and on subsequent zoom ins. If the user changes the position of the scrollbar while zoomed it, it wouldn't need to recenter on subsequent zooms. This was just more for initial scrollbar showing. Hopefully that makes sense. Whether its 'right or wrong' could be debated, but this is what I desire.  Let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: Are you using the browser specific zoom or the css property? Browser zoom is handled completely differently for each browser. You're not going to be able to compensate for it without javascript.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok - I am using the broswer specific zoom (in Chrome is says like "Zoom 125%" if that helps).

Comment: Some of the biggest sites on the Internet don't work with browser zoom (try Chrome on Amazon to see what I mean). Generally we create sites with 100% in mind. If everything breaks when a user uses the browser zoom, then it's on them.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 :) the problem is that you're looking at the wrong internets. try the isolated page: http://jsfiddle.net/ysyxV/show/

Comment: @MiniRagnarok That doesn't mean we as webdevelopers shouldn't care for zooming users. Trying to make your website look good under zoom is an effort that should be applauded.

Comment: @MrLister Absolutely. That's why I pointed him to javascript first. However, I frequently see people that don't realize how different the browsers can be.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 But this "problem" has nothing top do with zoom. The very same thing happens if the user makes the window narrower until the horizontal scrollbar appears. Are you saying you want the scrollbar to automatically go to the center then too? That would require Javascript.

Comment: @MrLister - I dont think I would want that.  It seems like the user experience from that might be a bit weird.  I dont want to force it to be in the center all the time, not allowing them to move to other sections of the page.  Just keep it centered when the horizontal scrollbar first appears and on subsequent zoom ins.  If the user changes the position of the scrollbar while zoomed it, it wouldn't need to recenter on subsequent zooms.  This was just more for initail scrollbar showing.  Hopefully that makes sense.  Whether its 'right or wrong' could be debated.

Comment: Everyone is different, to me the default user experience of zoom should be zooming in on the area that is centered on the page. On Chrome I see my zoom is somewhat to where I am looking. I would not want the screen to go somewhere else when I specifically zoomed in a certain area. Arguments on both sides of this topic

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, a rock-solid fix for that would be the following:

```
.wrapperDiv {
    text-align:center;
}

.centeredDiv {
    width: /*define yours*/ px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Use with caution